# OnActionExecutedAsync Not available in ActionFilterAttribute in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am porting over a action filter attribute from .net framework 4.6 to .net core 3.1 . One thing i noticed in .net core ActionFilterAttribute is that it , in .net core ther is no `OnActionExecutedAsync` Method.
Methods in ActionFilterAttribute  :-

```
public virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context);
public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context);
public virtual Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next);
public virtual void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context);
public virtual void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context);
public virtual Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next);
```

I have a couple of async methods that need to executed after the execution of the action . What would be the best practice to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OnActionExecutionAsync`, where you can invoke the `next` delegate and then run your own async logic after:

```cs
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
    ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var actionExecutedContext = await next();

    // .. Your awaits here.
}
```

The `next` delegate returns the `ActionExecutedContext`.